# Android - How to take a View from xml and use it in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-gridview

I have build a GridView in my xml file, now i want to fill it in a Fragment class. (this Fragment class use that layout)

userhome.xml

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/home_gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/user_avatar"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center" />
```

---

```
public class UserHomeFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.userhome, container, false);

}
```

I really don't know how to take my "home_gridview", I tried everything, but didn't work!
I need this, because i want to use it in one of my actionbar's tabs. Can you help me with some code please?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `GridView` inside `LinearLayout`(or some other layout) like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <GridView android:id="@+id/home_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_avatar"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in `onCreateView` find your `GridView` by id:

```
public class UserHomeFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.userhome, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_gridview);//must be your R not android.R
    //use your grid view

   return view;

}
```